# Can you filter at multiple levels?

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I have this data set named "Behavioral" (sample of much larger data set with 800 Stim.RT and Stim.ACC values for each subject at each session)

[image]

I want to get the overall mean Stim.RT and mean Stim.Acc for each Text category. For example, I would normally do this:

```
Dataset<-Behavioral%>%
  select(Subject, Session, Stim.ACC, Stim.RT, Text) %>%
  group_by(Text) %>%
  summarize(mean.ac = mean(Stim.ACC), mean.RT = mean(Stim.RT))
```

And it would return something like this:

[image]

The only issue is, **I want to filter out all the subject-session pairs whose mean.ac values are less than .50 BEFORE I get this second table back.**
Ie. If subject 1's mean.ac was .45 in session 1, I want all their session 1 values removed.

I tried this:

```
Dataset<-Behavioral%>%
  select(Subject, Session, Stim.ACC, Stim.RT, Text) %>%
  group_by(Subject, Session) %>%
  summarize(mean.ac = mean(Stim.ACC), mean.RT = mean(Stim.RT))%>%
  group_by(Text)
```

And I get this error: Error: Column `Text` is unknown

Answer (score 1):

`library(dplyr)`

```
Behavioral%>%
select(Subject, Session, Stim.ACC, Stim.RT, Text) %>%
group_by(Subject, Session) %>%
summarize(mean.ac = mean(Stim.ACC), mean.RT = mean(Stim.RT)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
filter(mean.ac >= 0.5) %>% 
select(Subject, Session) %>%
inner_join(Behavioral, by = c("Subject" = "Subject", "Session" = "Session")) %>%
select(Subject, Session, Stim.ACC, Stim.RT, Text) %>%
group_by(Text) %>%
summarize(mean.ac = mean(Stim.ACC), mean.RT = mean(Stim.RT)) %>%
ungroup()
```

So the reason you got the error is because `Text` was not part of the `group_by` function, and when you `summarise` after a `group_by`, the only variables in your resulting tibble are the variables in the `group_by` and the variables you create in `summarise`. So in your case, the resulting variables in

```
Dataset<-Behavioral%>%
select(Subject, Session, Stim.ACC, Stim.RT, Text) %>%
group_by(Subject, Session) %>%
summarize(mean.ac = mean(Stim.ACC), mean.RT = mean(Stim.RT))
```

are going to be `Subject`, `Session`, `mean.ac`, `mean.RT`.

Because of this, I filtered for when `mean.ac >= 0.5` per your requirements and only needed the `Subject` and `Session` which I `inner_join`ed to the original dataset so that the `Subject` and `Session` meeting the condition are included. `inner_join` is like a `join` and `filter`. Then I went ahead and calculated the `mean.ac` and `mean.RT` is for each `Text` post-`inner_join`.

Comment: THank you for this! I see how this would work. I am trying to run this and getting this error: Error in inner_join(tbl_df(x), y, by = by, copy = copy, ...) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default

Comment: Just re-edited. There was a missing pipe operator `%>%`

Comment: AHhh yes. Should have seen that myself! Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need three groups.

```
Dataset<-Behavioral%>%
  select(Subject, Session, Stim.ACC, Stim.RT, Text) %>%
  group_by(Subject, Session, Text) %>%
  summarize(mean.ac = mean(Stim.ACC), mean.RT = mean(Stim.RT))%>%
  filter(mean >= 0.5) %>%
  group_by(Text) %>%
  summarize(mean.ac = mean(mean.ac), mean.RT = mean(mean.RT))
```

Next time, try making a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/), so that we can work directly with your data.